# Redirection rule for https in htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, typo3, cloudflare

This is my htaccess code for redirecting non securing site to secure. but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Our website is historylearning.com and as you can see the site is non secure. Our site is hosted on OVH server and using Cloudflare . The site is built with Typo3 CMS .

How to configure the HTTPS properly for the website? Is there anything to check on either on OVH hosting or on Cloudflare?

Thanks

Comment: `This is my htaccess code for redirecting non securing site to secure.` But your rule is actually redirecting `https` to `http` not the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You could be missing an exclamation mark before "on" and change http to https in the third line.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Notice that this will lead to an endless loop if the target URL uses HTTP like in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is doing the opposite of what you want, if https is on it will redirect to http. If you change it to the following it should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Notice that it is safer to check for `!on` since `HTTPS` can also be empty with http://

Comment: I've changed the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Cloudflares [Summary of Page Rules Settings](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427#summary-of-page-rules-settings), especially "Always Use HTTPS"